# Error conectar data adapter a servidor vinculado de SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

espero me puedan apoyar, tengo en mi servidor SQL una base de datos vinculada de otro server, en el SSMS hago un query a sus tablas sin problemas, el detalle es al realizar una consulta desde C# que me arroja el error:

***System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'sa'.'***

Esta es mi linea de conexión:

> SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data 
>   Source = SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;User
>   ID=sa;Password=XXXXXXXX");

Esa conexion funciona bien directo a una tabla de la BD principal (no la vinculada)

[image: Detalles de conexion a BD vinculada]

[image: Detalles de conexion a BD vinculada]

Comment: Con qué usuario te conectas en el SSMS? Pudieras ser que sea un usuario diferente a sa, y que sa no tenga acceso al servidor vinculado.

Comment: Muchas gracias @KodiakMx, ya resolví el problema, revise el tema de usuarios como comentas y mejor genere un usuario nuevo en el servidor vinculado con permisos read/write para utilizarlo desde mi servidor principal y en SQL Server en las propiedades del servidor vinculado le quite la opción de "Suplantar" y agregue los datos de mi nuevo usuario remoto, ya con eso funciono. Saludos!

Comment: Excelente! Dejo el comentario como respuesta para futuras referencias.

Comment: es mala practica eso que estas haciendo, lo mejor que puedes hacer si son servidores vinculados, es trabajar con Store procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Documentando para futuras referencias)

Revisa tu usuario `sa` tengas acceso a la base de datos vinculada. O en su caso, utiliza un usuario que si tenga acceso a todas las bases de datos involucradas.